# Trying to print and sort file alphabetically, but also skip the first line in the file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm quite new to coding, and for an assignment I'm trying to show simply the items in the file, sorted alphabetically, without the name, price, etc.

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

print("")

data = fhand.readlines()
data.sort()
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i])
```

When I run this code, it sorts the file the way I want it alphabetically, but the first line in the file is included in this sorting process.

```
Flash, 300, 1, Figurine, Dc

Hulk, 100, 1, Figurine, Marvel

Name, Price, Quantity, Product, Brand

Obi Wan Kenobi, 400.99, 1, Figurine, Star Wars

Spiderman, 30.50, 1, Comic, Marvel

Superman, 150, 1, Figurine, DC

Wolverine, 20, 2, Comic, Marvel
```

Ignore the context of the file content lol, just playing around with file sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read all lines but store all except for the first line:

```py
fname = input("Enter the file name: ")
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print("File cannot be opened:", fname)
    exit()

print("")

# read all lines and store all lines except the first line:
data = fhand.readlines()[1:]

data.sort()
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i])
```